# Solving nonlinear overdetermined system using python

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to find a good way to solve a nonlinear overdetermined system with python. I looked into optimization tools here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.nonlin.html but I can't figure out how to use them. What I have so far is

```
#overdetermined nonlinear system that I'll be using
'''
a = cos(x)*cos(y)                           
b = cos(x)*sin(y)                           
c = -sin(y)                                   
d = sin(z)*sin(y)*sin(x) + cos(z)*cos(y)    
e = cos(x)*sin(z)                           
f = cos(z)*sin(x)*cos(z) + sin(z)*sin(x)    
g = cos(z)*sin(x)*sin(y) - sin(z)*cos(y)    
h = cos(x)*cos(z)
a-h will be random int values in the range 0-10 inclusive
'''
import math
from random import randint
import scipy.optimize

def system(p):
    x, y, z = p
    return(math.cos(x)*math.cos(y)-randint(0,10),
           math.cos(x)*math.sin(y)-randint(0,10),
           -math.sin(y)-randint(0,10),
           math.sin(z)*math.sin(y)*math.sin(x)+math.cos(z)*math.cos(y)-randint(0,10),
           math.cos(x)*math.sin(z)-randint(0,10),
           math.cos(z)*math.sin(x)*math.cos(z)+math.sin(z)*math.sin(x)-randint(0,10),
           math.cos(z)*math.sin(x)*math.sin(y)-math.sin(z)*math.cos(y)-randint(0,10),
           math.cos(x)*math.cos(z)-randint(0,10))

x = scipy.optimize.broyden1(system, [1,1,1], f_tol=1e-14)
```

could you help me out a bit here?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you right, you want to find an approximate solution to the non-linear system of equations `f(x) = b` where b is the vector containing the random values `b=[a,...,h]`.

In order to do this you will first need to remove the random values from the `system` function, because otherwise in each iteration the solver will try to solve a different equation system. Moreover, I think that the basic Broyden method only works for a system with as many unknowns as equations. Alternatively you could use `scipy.optimize.leastsq`. A possible solution looks like this:

```
# I am using numpy because it's more convenient for the generation of
# random numbers.
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint
import scipy.optimize

# Removed random right-hand side values and changed nomenclature a bit.
def f(x):
    x1, x2, x3 = x
    return np.asarray((math.cos(x1)*math.cos(x2),
                       math.cos(x1)*math.sin(x2),
                       -math.sin(x2),
                       math.sin(x3)*math.sin(x2)*math.sin(x1)+math.cos(x3)*math.cos(x2),
                       math.cos(x1)*math.sin(x3),
                       math.cos(x3)*math.sin(x1)*math.cos(x3)+math.sin(x3)*math.sin(x1),
                       math.cos(x3)*math.sin(x1)*math.sin(x2)-math.sin(x3)*math.cos(x2),
                       math.cos(x1)*math.cos(x3)))

# The second parameter is used to set the solution vector using the args
# argument of leastsq.
def system(x,b):
    return (f(x)-b)

b = randint(0, 10, size=8)
x = scipy.optimize.leastsq(system, np.asarray((1,1,1)), args=b)[0]
```

I hope this is of help for you. However, note that it is extremely unlikely that you will find a solution, especially when you generate random integers in the interval [0,10] while the range of `f` is limited to [-2,2]